# how to take where query as input in postgres using python

Tags: python, database, input, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to take where query as input in Postgres using python.
Can anyone help me?

```
cur.execute("SELECT * from home_curd where consumer_type="+a)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing parameters to the query:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM home_curd WHERE cosumer_type = %s", (a,))
```

You can also use parameterized query for this. That means you can call `execute` method from your cursor object and use the `pyformat` binding style, and it will do the escaping for you. For example, the following should be safe (and work):

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM home_curd WHERE consumer_type = %(consumer_type)s",
        {"consumer_type": a})
```